# Getting the nth values from request.getParameterMap()

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, dictionary, httprequest

I have some parameters which I get from `request.getParameterMap()` and I would like to iterate through the Map and take the nth value from each row in the Map. Below is an example of the data

Map contains:

```
recordNo:1,2,3,4,5,6
dob:19800101,19800201,'',19930101,19940101,19950302
addressLn1: well street, prince street,lewis street,edward street,mills street, #3 rich street
```

What i have is a Map that contains this data i would like to loop through the data and take nth record from the Map array. This is what i want

first iteration print:
1,19800101,well street

second iteration print:
2,19800201,prince street

**Code:**

```
 Map map = request.getParameterMap();

  for(int i = 0; i< map.size();i++){

    //how can i access the values with the array at the nth position            
     System.out.println("Value at " +i+ " " +map.get(i).toString());

   }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it is a map an not a list?

Comment: i got the values from a form there are elements with the same name

Comment: This SO question might be able to give you some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509391/how-to-get-the-one-entry-from-hashmap-without-iterating

Comment: The form POST has recordNo:1 recordNo:2, recordNo:3....

Comment: Why aren't you using generics?  It's much harder to figure out what you're asking about without generics.

Comment: Looking at what you're trying to do, this is basically the wrong way to do it. Create a POJO that contains `dob` and `address` (and whatever else) and add them to a `Map<Integer, MyPojo>` or just use an `ArrayList<MyPojo>`

Comment: Also, unless you're using a `TreeMap`, it isn't going to be ordered.

Comment: @BrianRoach i am going to try your approach thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is conceptually incorrect, hence all your problems.

You should instead keep data in a Java Bean:

```
public class MyBean {
    private String recordNo; // is it an int?
    private String dob; // is it a Date?
    private String addressLn1;
    // getters/setters omitted
}
```

then somehow add it to the `List<MyBean>` and iterate through it:

```
List<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
// list gets populated in some way, then
for(MyBean bean : list) {
     bean.getDob();
     ...
}
```

---

So it appears that you're dealing with HTTP request and get you parameters map from it. In this case **you can't just rely on the order of parameters on that map** - the order of `recordNo` array might (and most probably will) be different from the order of `dob` array.

What you need to do in your case is to give your inputs in HTML unique names, like `recordNo0`, `recordNo1`, `dob0`, `dob1` - so that you can guarantee that bod corresponds to the correct recordNo:

```
<c:forEach varStatus="status" items="${yourCollection}">
    <input type='text' name='recordNo${status.index}' value='some value'>
    <input type='text' name='dob${status.index}' value='some value'>
</c:forEach>
```

Then you need to iterate through your parameters in servlet or whatever you've got to construct your `MyBean`s and collecting them in the array:

```
List<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
for(int i=0; ;i++) {
    String recNo = request.getParameter("recordNo"+i);
    if(recNo == null) break;
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.setRecordNo(recNo);
    bean.setDob(request.getParameter("dob"+i));
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I am trying this right now i want to pass request.getParameterMap() into the list

Comment: so you should've started with that - that you've got parameters coming from HTTP request and you need to convert them into a better structure...

Comment: I cannot pass the request.getParameterMap()  into a List<Object> or ArrayList<Object>

Comment: I am trying this List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
studentList =  (List<Student>) request.getParameterMap(); but its not compling

Comment: updated my answer - you need to rename your parameters in HTML, you will never be able to make getParameterMap work

Comment: I have one problem here i can give them unique names but the names will not be able to correspond to that which you have when you add the 'i' to it. What can i do in that case?

Comment: I can get recordNo1233, recordNo5456546, dob1233, dob5456546 names like that cause i will append the recordNo to the name of the element since the elements are also dynamic in the view

Comment: All the elements in the view gets created in a <c:forEach> tag

Comment: Thank you very much this will work much appreciated wish i could have given you more points here