# How to get particular key and value from Map

Tags: java, collections

I have searched but could not find a way to print only single key, value pair for particular entry.

`map.containsValue(value) or map.containsKey(key)`

will only tell if particular value or key is available or not.
I want to print that particular key, value pair `if (value is available)`
In other link, They want to get the random value, if you do not know the key. Here I know key and value and want to print it for particular key and value.

Comment: What about `Object value = map.get(key); if ( value != null ) { ... }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the one entry from hashmap without iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509391/how-to-get-the-one-entry-from-hashmap-without-iterating)

Comment: Julien, they want to get the random value, if you do not know the key. here i know key and values and want to print it for particular value.

Comment: If you have both the key _and_ the value, why do you need the map to print them?

Comment: @HiteshKumar Right, my mistake. But if you already have the key, what's the problem? Just get the value and you have both.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no avalilable method in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html to get Entity from map if there is any key or value available.
Try below code if it help :

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
   Object value = map.get(key);
 System.out.println("Key : " + key +" value :"+ value);
 }
```

Comment: thanks sauumum, even i tried that before but doesn't work for me, i think i did some sily mistak, anyway thank you very much. i can't  do +1 :(

Answer (score 0):

Access  pair using Key   
 
  **DataType value =myMap.get(s);** 
Operation on value if u want (optional)       
myMap.put(s,value) 
and for accessing whole map use Iterator of Map.Entry set